# How to determine statistical significance of physics dataset?

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset, reproducible-research

I am working on a physics paper, which looks at the dependence of resistivity on physical temperature. I obtained data showing a linear trend of the form

$$\rho(T)=\rho_0[1+\alpha(T-T_0)]$$

Based on my data, I can calculate an average value for $\alpha$, as well as uncertainty, but I do not know how to obtain a p-value for the data. At the high end, the correlation is positive, but I hypothesized a negative correlation. How do I determine if my results for $\alpha$ are statistically significant? Here is the [full paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AL7ZN1Hhc4B4axEjkAUXBLpSaZN-zvxw/view?usp=sharing) if that helps.

Comment: Oh this is easy! *Data sets* are *never* significant (regardless of the discipline in which they originate). *Tests* are significant (or not).

Comment: With respect to your model there are a number of tests which may be relevant, which are you interested in? What specific null hypotheses?

Comment: What's unclear here is a suitable probability model. Which of these are parameters to be estimated (obtaining estimates of unobservables), which are variables (data)? For the variables, which are observed with error? What's a suitable model for the error?